# React state variables mysteriously changing before 'beforeunload' function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

UPDATE:
I created a minimum reproducible sample here:
https://react-wsaei2.stackblitz.io
Editor link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wsaei2

In my app I'm using a sendBeacon function in beforeunload to unlock a database document when someone closes the page without doing it themselves. Here's how I'm doing that in a useEffect with an empty array so it only runs once on start:

```
// Add event listener to run code before window closes
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unlockStory);
return () => {
  window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unlockStory);
}
```

And here's the unlockStory function:

```
const unlockStory = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (props.storyID && !success && !loggedOut) {
      console.log("Unlocking story. success, loggedOut", success, loggedOut);
      debugger;
      navigator.sendBeacon(`/api/stories/${props.storyID}/${loggedOut}/${success}`, JSON.stringify({body: {locked: true}}));
    }
    e.returnValue = "What's going on?";
  }
```

As you see I don't want the beacon to send every time - only if the loggedOut == false (i.e. I don't want to send the Beacon to unlock if the user is already logged out).

The problem is for some reason in the unlockStory function loggedOut is always false, even if it was true right beforehand! I put a manual refresh button on the page to check like so:

```
const handleRefresh = () => {
    console.log("Handling refresh: success, loggedOut", success, loggedOut);
    window.location.reload(false);
}
```

The output is:

```
Handling refresh: success, loggedOut false true
Unlocking story. success, loggedOut false false
```

WHYYY????

Another odd thing is that the `debugger;` line in the unlockStory function doesn't ever get triggered on normal refreshes or page closes, it only gets triggered on refreshes that are causes by me making file changes so npm automatically refreshes the open pages.

Please help, I'm at a loss, thank you!

Comment: first of all you aren't removing your listener, because you are instanciating a new function. You have to pass the reference of the listener you want to remove.

Comment: place `unlockStory` in the same `useEffect`

Comment: @xadm I did that, it didn't make any difference. The problem is still that the variables are being changed for some reason. 'success' and 'loggedOut' are both React state variables set by setSuccess and setLoggedOut . You can see in the output that loggedOut is going from true to false on reload, which is super confusing.

What's also very confusing is that the `debugger;` only fire sometimes, while the beacon gets sent every single time.

Comment: prepare working [example] on codesandbox or stackblitz

Comment: @xadm never done this before, I created one here on stackblitz: https://react-wsaei2.stackblitz.io  Not sure if you need the editor link; let me know.

Comment: @xadm is the minimal reproducible example I posted everything you need?

Comment: always editor link is better, anybody can fork, experiment, update, etc.

Comment: @xadm Added the editor link at the top of the post for you. Been working on the problem and still no idea why this is happening!

Comment: hitting the same issue, @YoungZaphod Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `success` and `loggedOut` (and other used variables) as effect dependencies.

```
useEffect(() => {

  const unlockStory = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Inside unlockStory. success, loggedOut:", success, loggedOut);
    if (!success && !loggedOut) {
      console.log("Inside if")
      navigator.sendBeacon(`/api/stories/`, JSON.stringify({body: {locked: true}}));
    }
    e.returnValue = "What's going on?";
  }

  // Add event listener to run code before window closes
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", unlockStory);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", unlockStory);
  }

}, [success, loggedOut]); // Run on every success or loggedOut change
```

There is no need to manually remove event listeners as:

> React also cleans up effects from the previous render before running the effects next time.

Sometimes is easier to use class based components:

```
class StartClass extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loggedOut: false,
      success: false,
      storyObj: {
        segCount: 2
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState( { loggedOut: true } );
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", this.unlockStory);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", this.unlockStory);
    }
  }

  handleRefresh = () => {
    let {success, loggedOut} = this.state
    console.log("Handling refresh: success, loggedOut", success, loggedOut);
    window.location.reload(true);
  }

  unlockStory = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let {success, loggedOut} = this.state
    console.log("Inside unlockStory. success, loggedOut:", success, loggedOut);
    if (!success && !loggedOut) {
      console.log("Inside if")
      navigator.sendBeacon(`/api/stories/`, JSON.stringify({body: {locked: true}}));
    }
    e.returnValue = "What's going on?";
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container fluid>

        <Row>
          <Col>
          <p>
            To reproduce:<br/> Open console, then click the Refresh page button below. When the alert pops up check the console and you'll see that the loggedOut variable has changed from true to false.
          </p>
          <p>
            The same behavior occurs when you refresh via the browser, but you can't see the log as the console is cleared upon refresh.
          </p>
          {this.state.loggedOut && <Button onClick={this.handleRefresh}>Refresh page</Button>}
          </Col>
        </Row>


      </Container>
    );

  }
}
```

Comment: adding them as dependencies did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: @CarsonHolmes says nothing ... ask your own question with minimal working example ... answer has been accepted, the problem has been solved, you can explore working example with proposed code change