# api stuck in pending state on beforeunload event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome

I am trying to call the post api as soon the user tries to closes the tab.
my code is like this

```
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.getTriggeredOnBeforeUnload);
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.getTriggeredOnBeforeUnload);
  }

getTriggeredOnBeforeUnload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    navigator.sendBeacon(URL, payload)
    axios.post(URL,payload).then(res => {});
    e.returnValue = 'Are you sure you want to close?';
  }
```

when the dialog comes up i can see this api went through in firefox, but in chrome request is stuck in pending state. in chrome it works only when by clicking the cancel in dialog box. is there any workaround to fix that ?
UPDATE: TRIED USING THE navigator sendBeacon still it is in pending state

Comment: `addEventListener` registers an event handler. You need to add it once only. You can remove it from `componentWillUnmount`. About the API itself... I can't tell 100% sure... But if it is async. It logically should not work.

Comment: OR I would try to rely only on React... And do only `componentWillUnmount(){ this.getTriggeredOnBeforeUnload() }`

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette you mean to say sync function would work for this use case ?if so how do i write one here?

Comment: have no idea what handlecalltheapi really is.... But the function name allows to assume a request to a DB or a REST ressource. That can't be sync.

Comment: i have even followed the answer mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048009/react-state-variables-mysteriously-changing-before-beforeunload-function but still the api is in pending state in chrome, but works in firefox

Comment: UPDATE: above code works its just that call is in pending state in network, however i can see the call made in service.